# What are the possible parameters to wfuseimg in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, wavelet-transform

The function [`wfuseimg`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wfusimg.html) fuses two images using wavelets.

However, its documentation is quite poor (for MATLAB standards) and lacks general description. Particularly, on which options exist for each of the inputs.

What are the possible inputs for `WNAME` `AFUSMETH` and `DFUSMETH`?

Comment: It's relatively poor but still the page you link describe the possible inputs somewhat. Just see "Fusmeth denotes...see wfusmat.". Anything in particular you are interested in?

Comment: @Trilarion what about `WNAME`?

Comment: It's not a real solution but you could use the `Wavelet Analyzer app` in order to see which parameter can be used in the drop-down menu.

Comment: wfuseimg uses wname only in wfustree, which uses it in wdectree, which uses it in wfilters and liftwave, which use it in wavetype, which uses wavenames. With `wavenames('all')` you kind of get a list, but I have no idea what each entry means.

Comment: @Trilarion obchardon feel free to add that as an answer

Comment: Ho it looks like there is more info [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ug/wavelet-families-additional-discussion.html)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I kind of assembled an answer. I don't expect it to be the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WName`

is probably the name of the wavelet being used. Analyzing the code, it seems to be used in functions `wfustree`, `wdectree`, `wfilters` and `liftwave`. The set of possible values can probably be obtained by calling

```
wavenames('all');
```

giving something like: "lazy", "hair", "db..", "sym..", "coif..", "bior..", .. There is more explanation about the wavelets themselves [in here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/gs/introduction-to-the-wavelet-families.html).

Not all of them are valid for use with wfuseimg ("lazy", "bs3", "rbs3", "9.7", "r9.7" are not valid).

`AFUSMETH` and `DFUSMETH`

are somewhat explained in the documentation. They are either a simple string ('max', 'min', 'mean', 'img1', 'img2' or 'rand') or a struct with "name" and  "param" field. The names are "linear", "UD_fusion", ... and some explanation of the parameter is given at [wfusmat](https://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/wfusmat.html).

A or D probably mean application to "approximations coefficients" and "details coefficients" but I'm just guessing this from the documentation.

Comment: however not all of those are valid! Just the first, `lazy` is not valid. Most of the others seem good. I will leave this question open for a while, hoping to see someone with more info perhaps. If not, I will accept your answer in a while

Comment: @AnderBiguri Added that info to the answer.

Comment: The last 4 are not valid either: `bs3` `9.7` `r9.7` and `rbs3`. The rest seem OK